# How to dispatch delayed (pending) job in Redis queue?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

There is `start()` method that queue a job with delay in 10 minutes:

```
public function start()
{
    StopSomethingJob::dispatch($smth)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
}
```

How to make the method `finish()` dispatch declared `StopSomethingJob` job right away without waiting 10 minutes?

```
public function finish()
{
   //TODO:: Find and fire pending job
}
```

**UPD**: .env

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
```

Comment: why dont you dispatch `StopSomethingJob` in the method `finish()` directly ? Anyway, I guess you can do it by updating the values `available_at` in the `jobs` table in the DB.

Comment: @N69S Dispatching `StopSomethingJob` in the `finish()` method with `dispatchNow()`  will do a work, but the delayed job from the `start()` method will still be in the Redis queue.

Comment: Use `dispatch()` not `dispatchNow()` otherwise you will have some issues with the `finish()` method of `StopSomethingJob` (will not be triggered). The job will be available right away and run if the worker is available.